# Использование метода resample для преобразования структуры временного ряда

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

У меня есть временной ряд с месячными таймрефмами. Допустим, выглядит он так:

```
date    fz
2013-01-01  2.780300e+11
2013-02-01  3.646940e+11
2013-03-01  4.543250e+11
2013-04-01  5.842260e+11
2013-05-01  4.436440e+11
2013-06-01  4.171660e+11
2013-07-01  5.243020e+11
2013-08-01  4.557350e+11
2013-09-01  4.517440e+11
2013-10-01  7.839200e+11
```

Далее мне необходимо перевести его в квартальные таймфремы. Делаю я это, используя pandas.resample.

```
data_q = data.resample('QS', axis=0).mean()
```

На выходе получаю следующий датасет:

```
date    fz
2013-01-01  3.656830e+11
2013-04-01  4.816787e+11
2013-07-01  4.772603e+11
2013-10-01  7.839200e+11
```

Передо мной стоит задача выводить только полные кварталы. Следовательно, последний квартал в данном случае лишний, так как для его завершения не хватает 11 и 12 месяцев. Итоговая таблица должна была выглядеть следющим образом:

```
date    fz
2013-01-01  3.656830e+11
2013-04-01  4.816787e+11
2013-07-01  4.772603e+11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то мне пока ничего не придумалось умнее этого:

```
res = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.to_period('Q')).filter(lambda x: len(x)==3).groupby(df['date'].dt.to_period('Q')).mean()
```

res:

```
                  fz
date                
2013Q1  3.656830e+11
2013Q2  4.816787e+11
2013Q3  4.772603e+11
```

Думаю, стоит отметить, что если `date` у вас является индексом, то перед указанной операцией нужно сделать `reset_index`